# Change text colour of TextView in Tab

Tags: android, tabs

In my Android application I have a `TabHost` which contains multiple tabs. To create each tab, I call a function called `createTabView` which looks like this:

```
private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text, int layoutId) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    if (tv != null) {
        tv.setText(text.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()));
        if(text.toLowerCase().equals("special")){
            tv.setTextColor(R.color.gold);
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

The above basically adds the appropriate text to the `TextView` and colours the `TextView` to gold if the string is "special".

The problem however is that it doesn't render gold as it should. It renders a very dark blue colour.

I can confirm that `R.color.gold` is definitely gold. I have used it in many places. I have also tried system colours too but they do not work either. It always shows as a dark blue colour.

Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094654/setting-android-textview-text-color-programmatically-with-settextcolor-renders

Comment: May I ask why you don't use ActionBar tabs or ViewPagerIndicator(https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) or the one similar to Play Store tabs https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use-

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
```

Comment: Oh god! That worked. Why the hell does my version not work? It has two overloads, one asks for an integer (for a colour). Jeeeeeeeeeeeez!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
  for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
          tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));
        TextView tv = (TextView)   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));    

    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));
    TextView tv = (TextView)   tabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));      
}
```

and this method

```
  @Override
   public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));
    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#colorcode"));
}
```